# Can I update already existing apk using bks file ?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, jks

One of my friend have developed one android app in Eclipse before 2 years. Now I have developed its updated version in Android studio. Now I want to generate updated signed apk in android studio but I have only 3 things. Alias, Password and .bks file. Can I generate signed apk in android studio using mentioned things ? Before 2 years  does Eclipse using .bks file to generate signed apk ?
Please Help

Comment: did you tried generating signed apk in android studio? I think you should be able to generate since you have keystore file.

Comment: That i know, but I have only .bks file then what to do ? @PareshMayani